# Angular and JSON

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm implementing a simple system to import JSON elements in Angular.
Everything works fine: I've used an interface, an observable and a directive. You can find the JSON here: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos

Now, I want to use "completed", the boolean from JSON file, to display or not users when the page is loaded. There is a boolean "showUSer" and a method "displayUSer()" but I don't get it...
I cannot correctly retrieve this JSON data.
*Any ideas ?* :>

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

interface JSP {
  "userId": string;
  "id": string;
  "title": string;
  "completed": boolean
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  template: `<div class="display" *ngFor="let todo of todos">
              <div>User Id: {{todo.userId}}</div>
              <div >id: {{todo.id}}</div>
              <div *ngIf="showUser">Title: {{todo.title}}</div>
            </div>`,
  styles: ['.display {margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;}']
  })

export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string = "Products List";
  todos: JSP[];
  showUSer: boolean;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.http.get<JSP[]>('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
    .subscribe(result => this.todos = result);
 }

 displayUSer(): void {
   this.showUSer = this.todos.completed;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nitpicks: Your question says `to display or not users` but your code seems to be `display or not the title`.  Also why do you capitalize the 'S' in 'USers'?

The problem is this function which seems to ignore your actual data layout:

```js
 displayUSer(): void {
   this.showUSer = this.todos.completed;
 }
```

`todos` is a property of your controller.  This is an array from the api call you make and it doesn't contain a `completed` property, so `this.todos.completed` will always be false.  I'm a little surprised that you don't get an error compiling your typescript.

It looks like you want this flag to be on a 'todo item' basis and not page-wide, so `this.showUSer` doesn't make sense.  Also you don't seem to be calling `displayUSer` to set the value in any case.

Since you are looking at an individual todo item and the query is simple, why don't you just look at the flag?

```html
<div *ngIf="todo.completed">Title: {{todo.title}}</div>
```

If you *are* wanting to set a page-wide flag based on some critieria, you can do that when you subscribe to the results.  Here I'm assuming that you will set the `showUSer` flag if *any* of the todo items is marked as completed:

```js
    this.http.get<JSP[]>('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
    .subscribe(result => {
        this.todos = result;
        this.showUSers = result.reduce((previous, current) => previous || current.completed, false);
    });
```

Comment: You're right. The name of my method is not accurate. I should have use "showTitle" instead of "showUser".
Thanks for your help! Your answer exceeds my expectations :)

Answer (score 1):

Your **JSON** hasn't any `json.completed` value, but `json[_].completed`.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed JSON value and it works.
But I want that the "Title" display when "completed" is true and not display when "false".

Comment: Change in your template `<div *ngIf="todo.completed">Title: {{todo.title}}</div>`